# The home router "/" in express-generator is being overwritten somewhere, or it's just not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express-generator

I am trying to connect `mongodb` with `express-generator`. My default home router `"/"` is in index.js, but it's not working. It's not invoked. It only works if I change the router to something else.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('here')
  const collection = req.app.locals.collection;
  collection.find({})
  .toArray()
  .then(data => res.json(data))
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my index.js.

And in my app.js, I have this:

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, client)=>{
    if(err) console.log('we have an error: ', err)
    const db = client.db('MovieGoers');
    const collection = db.collection('users')
    app.locals.collection = collection;
})

app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

It's not working. The function is not invoked. If I change the router in index.js to `"/movies"` or anything else, it works in that router, but the default home router `"/"` is not working. Nothing is invoked. I keep seeing the "welcome to express" header from the index.html.

Is something overwriting this router?

Comment: You did not provided enough code to see but that means you mounting  route `/` more than once and do you think `app.use('/', homeRouter);` is fine or should be `app.use('/', indexRouter);`

Comment: I meant to say indexRouter, not homeRouter. I was just testing with a different page to see if it would make a difference. So, you're saying my page is mounted twice? How do I fix that? The rest of the code is just the default code when you install npm.

Comment: @ArifKhan This is the entire app js code: https://jsfiddle.net/0j9vc76h/ I've already copied the entire index js code above. The rest of the app is a public folder which has index html, and then we have the node_modules, and bin, which has a www page, which contains a bunch of code I don't understand. It's this: https://jsfiddle.net/0j9vc76h/1/

Comment: @ArifKhan Then we have the package json file, inside which I see the `start` property links to `./bin/www"` here, I already copied the content of `www` above.